# Two Facebook apps in one project swift - Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have two apps developed with swift Sign in facebook, then I have two apps on facebook. But now I need to join these two apps in one, which will have a screen where the user must choose between the common login or PRO login, each login that is related to one of the apps on facebook. But to set up my project in xcode, I need to add the key to the facebook app on my plist, but setting this up if I have two different Facebook apps?

Comment: So what is your SPECIFIC question?

Comment: how to sdk configuration to be able to login in two different fb-apps? and that apparently is not possible to programmatically select an app in execussão time. the sdk settings is made in info.plist with a key "FacebookAppID" can not make a new key "FacebookAppID2" and select it. it would be possible to do this in any way? @DuncanC

Comment: Hey Athila , Have you found solution for your issue ? I have same problem and searching over the net to know how to set two appID in single plist. please let me know if you got something.

Comment: not yet @Pankaj